# How to ensure INSERT order using two prepared statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I've got two prepared statements:

- Batched INSERT that binds values to insert 5 rows at a time.
- Single INSERT that binds values to insert just a single element at a time.

My goal is to ensure that statements are finished in the order they are invoked. It seems like even after calling `db.serialize()` the ordering is not maintained. Example code inserts 5 elements every spin of the loop, changing the method of insertion from 5x Single Insert to 1x Batched Insert, and back:

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./TestDatabase.db');

db.serialize();
db.run(
    `
    CREATE TABLE Test (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, AssignedID INTEGER NOT NULL, InsertType TEXT);
    `
);

const insertSingleStatement = db.prepare(
    `
    INSERT INTO Test (AssignedID, InsertType) VALUES (?, 'Single')
    `
);
const insertFiveStatement = db.prepare(
    `
    INSERT INTO Test (AssignedID, InsertType) VALUES (?, 'Many'),(?, 'Many'),(?, 'Many'),(?, 'Many'),(?, 'Many')
    `
);

var AssignedID = 1;
var InsertMany = true;
var InsertionsToDo = 500;

while(InsertionsToDo > 0) {
    if (InsertMany) {
        insertFiveStatement.run(AssignedID++, AssignedID++, AssignedID++, AssignedID++, AssignedID++);
        InsertionsToDo -= 5;
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            insertSingleStatement.run(AssignedID++);
            --InsertionsToDo;
        }
    }
    InsertMany = !InsertMany;
}
```

I'd expect `ID` matching `AssignedID`. `AssignedID` is incremented every insert operation and if all insert's order were just as their `.run()` order they'd match perfectly. It's not the case. Seems the batched inserts come far after the single inserts:

| ID | AssignedID | InsertType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | Single |
| 2 | 7 | Single |
| 3 | 8 | Single |
| 4 | 9 | Single |
| 5 | 10 | Single |
| … | … | … |
| 248 | 498 | Single |
| 249 | 499 | Single |
| 250 | 500 | Single |
| 251 | 1 | Many |
| 252 | 2 | Many |
| 253 | 3 | Many |
| 254 | 4 | Many |